# Ambient isotopy of the diagonal submanifold in product space

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Given a closed manifold $M^n$ and its $k$-fold product space $M^n\times\cdots\times M^n$,Can the diagonal submanifold $\Delta:=\{(m,\cdots,m)\in (M^n)^k\mid m\in M\}$ be isotopied to the submanifold
$M\times \{\ast\}\times\cdots\times \{\ast\}$?

For some particularly nice manifold,i tend to believe,the answer is positive.Say torus $T^n$.
In general,I guess,this is not true.

(Following the idea from the classification of knot theory,I think,a good understanding of the diagonal complement would help here.Say, for the $k=2$ case,the diagonal complement is a fiber bundle over $M$ with fiber $M-\{\ast\}$.But $M\times M-M\times\{\ast\}$ is always a trivial bundle.)

> 1.Are there some more examples for $k\geq 3?$
>
> 2.Have people already established some criterion for the existence of such an isotropy or any obstruction theory in terms of the algebraic topology of $M$? Are there some nice references on this topic?

Comment: Try homology classes, using the Kunneth formula.

Comment: Check out "Morse theory and Stokes' theorem" to find out what's really true about isotoping the diagonal. http://intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/sdg/2002/0007/0001/SDG-2002-0007-0001-a009.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is always no for $M$ a closed manifold.

If $\Delta: M\to M\times M$ were isotopic into the first factor, then in particular it would be homotopic to a map $\Delta': M\to M\times M$ with image in $M\times \{ \ast\}$. Then the composition of $\Delta$ with projection onto the second factor $pr_2\circ \Delta: M\to M$ would be homotopic to $pr_2\circ\Delta'$, therefore null-homotopic. But this composition is the identity map, and $M$ is not contractible.

The same argument works with more factors.